# Капча от гугла при регистрации

Tags: php

При попытке добавить капчу от гугла на форму регистрации, получаю ошибку

```
Deprecated
: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ReCaptcha has a deprecated constructor in
recaptchalib.php
on line
40
```

В файле на 40 строке
class ReCaptcha

Comment: фактически это не ошибка, а уведомление, что данный синтаксис устарел

Comment: @teran А как избавиться или скрыть? Просто её видно на странице

Comment: чтобы избавиться - переписать конструктор через [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php), либо отключить `E_DEPRECATED` в `error_reporiting`. Вообще странно, что капча гугла такое выдает, вы ее  с официальных источников качали, это современная версия вообще?

Comment: Взята с офф сайта

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете старую версию библиотеки: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php

Актуальная версия: https://github.com/google/recaptcha